# Number grouping to minimize the negative score (optimization problem)

Tags: optimization, grouping, minimization

I've got a project in the programming section. At first, I thought it was easy, but now I'm completely stuck! The project is about grouping numbers containing arrays like this:

```
Number = [150, 240, 285, 420, 200, 605, 490, 745, 455]
Count = [283, 358, 10, 128, 308, 24, 10, 10, 22]
```

This means that there are 283 copies of 150 and so on.

There are two conditions for this project:

1. the maximum sum of group members shouldn't exceed 1200;
2. each group with a sum less than 1200 will get a negative score equal to its distance from 1200.

This project aims to minimize the total negative score. The output is the groups and total negative score. Note that those arrays are inputs, but the limit (1200) is always the same. I tried greedy programming in Python to group them, but with this amount of numbers, it's not optimal and takes too much time and resources to complete, and more importantly, it always returns the wrong answer.

One (and wrong!) code I used:

```
def group_numbers(numbers, target_sum):
    if not numbers:
        return [[]]
    
    results = []
    for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
        if num <= target_sum:
            remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
            sub_results = group_numbers(remaining, target_sum - num)
            for sub_result in sub_results:
                result = [num] + sub_result
                results.append(result)

    return results


numbers = [5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2]
groups = []
unused_numbers = numbers.copy()

while unused_numbers:
    num = max(unused_numbers)
    if num > 12:
        unused_numbers.remove(num)
        continue

    valid_groups = group_numbers(unused_numbers, 12 - num)
    if not valid_groups:
        unused_numbers.remove(num)
        continue

    best_group = max(valid_groups, key=len)
    groups.append(best_group)
    for n in best_group:
        unused_numbers.remove(n)

# Remove duplicate groups
unique_groups = []
for group in groups:
    if group not in unique_groups:
        unique_groups.append(group)

print(unique_groups)
```

I needed to change the numbers and limit (1200 to 12) to simplify.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.